# MultiLine Regex search in VisualStudio?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I need to insert into DB all text literals that are in a web page.

Looking at

```
<article>
  <h2 class="f5_Heading">
     Marketing
  </h2>
</article>
```

I need to find "Marketing"

So I did this regex search in Visual studio search :

`\>[^\<]#\<`

[image]

But it doesn't find it. however  it *does* find this :

[image]

Notice : there is *no* line breaks .

**Question:**

I don't understand why it doesn't find it in the first Regex :

The `[^\<]#` means : *anything* which is not a closing tag characters.

How can I enhance my regex to match also multilines ?

Comment: What is `#` in your regex means?

Comment: @AvinashRaj `#`=lazy `+?` for Visual Studio where `@` is lazy `*?`

Comment: try `(?<=\>)[^\<]#(?=\<)` or `(?<=\>)[^\<]*(?=\<)`

Comment: @AvinashRaj read here for more information http://www.aaronlerch.com/blog/2007/03/28/visual-studio-find-and-replace-regular-expressions/

Comment: @AvinashRaj there is no `()` groups in vs regex. there is however `{}` - but still doesnt work :-(

Comment: @AvinashRaj VS2013 actually allows you to use full-blown .NET regexes in its search, but VS2010 unfortunately has its own syntax. Oh, and *IIRC*, even in VS2013, `\n` isn't included in `\s` for some odd reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regex

```
(?<=>)\n?\s*\w+
```

The above will match the "Marketing" and also the spaces before it. In C# you would want something like

```
(?m)(?<=>)\n?\s*\w+
```

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/iS7aM0/1)

Comment: I'm talking about Visual Studio search here. there is no "returned group" thing , or "here are the matches". Where do you see in the picture a returned group thing ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir I know. My regex will only match Marketing including the space before it.

Comment: @RoyiNamir check the demo too.

Comment: @RoyiNamir what's `:b`? and why are you escaping `>`?

Comment: @RoyiNamir try now with `(?m)` multiline flag

Comment: becuase of this http://i.imgur.com/woTznrA.png ( as people already said here , the VS regex is different....)

Comment: @RoyiNamir also, you're modifying my regex. Use my regex as is and see if it works. `(?m)` is multiline flag. If there is another syntax, use it or if it searches multiline by default, then remove it.

Comment: @RoyiNamir dunno, but VS 2010 seems to have different syntax. Can't you use 2013 Express? Submlime editor or VIM can also be used.